# Undebuggable non-deterministic heisenbug in single-threaded C++ function call

Tags: c++, debugging, object-lifetime, heap-corruption, non-deterministic

I'm at the end of my rope here: I have a single-threaded C++ program. Here is some empirical data and background information, I tried to highlight the most important keywords;

- The entire section I'm talking about does **not have any syscalls**, other than the **memory (de-)allocation calls the standard C++ library** may perform (`std::set`s are involved). It's a purely logical algorithm.
- The behaviour of this **should be deterministic**, depending on the input, which I do not vary.
- If the bug manifests itself, the program simply falls into what looks like an **endless loop** where it seems to start **allocating memory beyond any bound**.
- The bug does **not** manifest itself **predictably**, I can run the program from the command line and sometimes (perhaps 30%-50%) the bug manifests itself, otherwise, everything runs smoothly and correctly as far as I can tell.
- Once I run the program not directly from the prompt, but in **gdb or valgrind, the bug is gone**, the program never dies.
- Now comes the best part: I traced the problem to a (templated) **non-virtual member function call**. Just **before the call**, I print a message to `std::cout`, which **I can see** in the terminal. The **first line** inside the function also has a debug message, which is **never shown**.

I don't see any reasonable explanation any more. Maybe you can come up with an idea how to proceed.

---

Edit: The significant lines of code, I changed the line numbers so we can refer to them and omitted irrelevant parts, so not everything seems to make the best sense.

a.cpp

```
 10     std::set<Array const*>* symbols;
 11     std::set<Array const*> allSymbols;
 12     symbols = &allSymbols;
 //  ... allSymbols are populated with std::inserter
 15     std::cout << "eval; cd = " << &cd << ", cg = " << &cd.cg << std::endl;
 16     senderConstraints = cd.cg.eval(*symbols);
```

b.cpp

```
 31     template <typename ArrayContainer>
 32     ConstraintList eval(ArrayContainer const request) {
 33       std::cout << "inside eval ... going to update graph now" << std::endl;
```

The last line of output is:

```
eval; cd = 0x2e6ebb0, cg = 0x2e6ebc0
```

Then it's trapped in the endless loop.

Comment: If your really are sure that this is not a race condition (effects look exactly like what you describe), i would dump the state of my objects to see which state leads to the bug-state. some wrong initialisation order can also lead to such behaviour.

Comment: Code would help, otherwise it's kind of impossible to tell anything. However "bug is magically gone in debugger" usually points to a constellation of `if(ptr != NULL) do_something(); ` and a non-initialized variable. If the memory location is accidentially zero, the bug does not occur, otherwise it does. The debugger zero-initializes **all** variables (even the ones you didn't), so the bug is "magically gone".

Comment: You can try to trace system calls (some may be hidden inside the system libraries) with [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace). Also consider adding **lots** of debug printing, the more the better.

Comment: It's possible your program is implicitly relying on some uninitialised stack variable, which Valgrind will not catch.

Comment: @MareInfinitus: Well, how can it be a race condition if I only have one thread and don't really communicate with anything other than the part of the kernel that gives me heap memory?

Comment: @Damon: I didn't think the concrete code would be so useful, but I tried to extract the most important parts.

Comment: I suspect the bug is between lines 12 and 15. Note that `*symbols` is passed by value, so the `std::set` is copied. If the state of the `set` is somehow corrupted, this may lead to the endless loop. Try passing `request` by const refernce and see if this changes anything.

Comment: And why do you use `*symbols` and not `allSymbols`? Surely `allSymbols` is not out of scope here?

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but why pass `request` into `eval` by value? It should be more effective to pass it by reference instead (no copying etc.). Come to think of it, maybe this copying of pointers in the set might be related to your problem?

Comment: Yeah, I just found the bug, and it's so embarrassing I hesitate to post the solution ... okay, let's be brave ... `allSymbols` wasn't in the same scope as `eval`, so it was destructed but the pointer was still sitting in `symbols`. Gosh, I hate these stupid things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet, the second line is printed, when you change

```
ConstraintList eval(ArrayContainer const request)
```

to

```
ConstraintList eval(ArrayContainer const & request)
```

If so, either the state of `allSymbols` is corrupted between line 12 and line 15, or your code really looks more like this:

```
std::set<Array const*>* symbols;
{
    std::set<Array const*> allSymbols;
    symbols = &allSymbols;
    //  ... allSymbols are populated with std::inserter
}
std::cout << "eval; cd = " << &cd << ", cg = " << &cd.cg << std::endl;
senderConstraints = cd.cg.eval(*symbols);
```

Which is UB, because symbols refers to an already destructed object.

Comment: Yes I was blind, sorry. Good guess, though. To my defence though, the actual thing looks a bit more complicated.